# Try to prove: $ (A\times B)\cap (C\times D) = (A\cap C)\times(A\cap C) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Hi I'm trying to prove the following claim, even though **I know it is not true**, I "can" prove ...

Want to prove this:
$$ (A\times B)\cap (C\times D) = (A\cap C)\times(A\cap C) $$

My try $\subseteq$:
$$ <x,y>\in (A\times B)\cap (C\times D)$$ 
$$ <x,y>\in (A\times B) and <x,y>\in (C\times D)$$ 
$$ x\in A $$ 
$$ and \Rightarrow y\in B $$ 
$$ and \Rightarrow x\in C $$ 
$$ and \Rightarrow y\in D $$

$$so \Rightarrow  x \in A\cap C $$
$$and \Rightarrow  y \in B\cap D $$
$$so \Rightarrow <x,y>\in  (A\cap C)\times(B\cap D)$$

For $\supseteq$  it look like this prove only in revere.

Where am I lying here? 
Also, is it true?
$$(A\times B)∩(C\times D)=(A\times D)∩(C\times B)$$
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your first question. For the second question, "is it true?
$(A×B)∩(C×D)=(A×D)∩(C×B)$"

$\langle x,y \rangle \in (A×B)∩(C×D) \iff \langle x,y \rangle \in (A×B) \wedge \langle x,y \rangle \in (C×D)$
$$\Rightarrow (x \in A \wedge y \in B) \wedge (x \in C \wedge y \in D)$$ 
Becuase of the communativity of 'and ($\wedge$)
$$ \Rightarrow(x \in A \wedge y \in C) \wedge (x \in C \wedge  y \in D)$$
$$\Rightarrow  \langle x,y \rangle \in (A\times D) \cap (C \times B)$$

So, now we have just proved $(A×B)∩(C×D)\subseteq(A×D)∩(C×B)$ only when $x,y \in A,B,C,D$ is a true statement. The only time $x,y \in A,B,C,D$ is false is when $A,B,C,D = \emptyset$. By plugging in this case into the equation, we can see our proof is still true.

Now, see if you can prove $(A×B)∩(C×D)\supseteq(A×D)∩(C×B)$ to prove both sets are equal.